# Express app with Realtime DataBase crashed, error: The default Firebase app does not exist

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

Express REST Api with TypeScript, using Firebase's RealTime DataBase. Brief summary of the initial steps taken in the implementation for the stack discussed:

1. Start by defining the necessary environment variables in a .env file, including the private key and database URL.

[image]

```
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=""
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY=""
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL="...firebaseio.com"
```

2. Define the necessary models and interfaces for the User data structure in Realtime Database, including the hashed password and address information.
3. Create a server.ts file that sets up the Express app, imports the necessary packages, and defines the necessary middleware, such as cors and body-parser.

   ```
   import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
   import cors from 'cors';

   import app from './app';

   export function start() {
     app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
     app.use(cors());

     const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
     app.listen(port, () => {
       console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${address.port}`);
     });
   }
   ```
4. Create a separate app.ts file that defines the endpoints and routes for the REST API. Import and use the dotenv library to load environment variables into the project.

   import dotenv from 'dotenv';
   import firebase from 'firebase-admin';
   import express from 'express';

   ```
   import router from './routes/user.route';
   import { start } from './server';

   dotenv.config();

   firebase.initializeApp({
     credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
       projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
       privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
       clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
     }),
     databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
   });

   start();

   const app = express();

   app.use('/signup', router);
   app.use('/login', router);
   app.use('/user/:userId', router);

   export default app;
   ```

Run start nodemon and i get the error: *'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.'*

Dependencies installed:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
  "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
  "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
  "express": "^4.18.2",
  "firebase": "^9.17.1",
  "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
  "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
  "typescript": "^4.9.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
  "@types/cors": "^2.8.13"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firebase configuration is fine. The problem is with how you have `app` / `server` files importing each other and with your app's import execution order.

If `app.ts` runs first, it first runs `import { start } from './server';`. Inside that file it then goes back to `app` and imports `import app from './app';`. This is a circular dependency which you want to avoid. I'll provide more details.

Simplify things to start and just have a `index.ts` and remove your `app.ts` and `server.ts` until you understand the import order.

Notice below we make sure to thread `app` to the `router` module. When you break these components down into smaller parts like you did, you need to carefully pass the instantiated Express app to the modules that need it.

**Example index.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import router from './routes/user.route';

dotenv.config();

firebase.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/signup', router);
app.use('/login', router);
app.use('/user/:userId', router);

router(app); // <--- ensures express app is started first before defining routes

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${address.port}`);
});
```